# vagrant-windows chef-solo provisioner fails with "failed to launch waiter thread:1455 (fatal)"

Tags: windows, chef-infra, vagrant, chef-solo

I'm having a problem with the vagrant-windows chef-solo provisioner failing with the error below.

The solo.rb and dna.json files are successfully written to c:/tmp/vagrant-chef-1 on the guest machine and when I manually run the powershell script sent to windows from vagrant, chef executes as expected.

Any ideas on what could be going on or how I can go about troubleshooting this?

### _

---

- *Host: Mac OSX 10.8.4*
- *Guest: Windows Server 2012*
- *Provider: VirtualBox 4.2.14*

---

Here's the error I'm getting...

```
[default] Running provisioner: VagrantPlugins::Chef::Provisioner::ChefSolo...
Generating chef JSON and uploading...
Running chef-solo...
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/run_lock.rb:58:in `flock': failed to launch waiter thread:1455 (fatal)
    from C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/run_lock.rb:58:in `acquire'

    from C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/client.rb:446:in `do_run'
    from C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/client.rb:200:in `run'

    from C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/application.rb:190:in `run_chef_client'
    from C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:239:in `block in run_application'

    from C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:231:in `loop'
    from C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:231:in `run_application'

    from C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/application.rb:73:in `run'
    from C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/bin/chef-solo:25:in `<top (required)>'

    from C:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-solo:23:in `load'
    from C:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-solo:23:in `<main>'
ERROR warden: Error occurred: Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
ERROR warden: Error occurred: Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
ERROR warden: Error occurred: Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
ERROR vagrant: Vagrant experienced an error! Details:
ERROR vagrant: #<VagrantPlugins::Chef::Provisioner::Base::ChefError: Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.>
ERROR vagrant: Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
ERROR vagrant: /Users/David/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-windows-1.0.3/lib/vagrant-windows/monkey_patches/chef_solo.rb:51:in `run_chef_solo_on_windows'
/Users/David/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-windows-1.0.3/lib/vagrant-windows/monkey_patches/chef_solo.rb:12:in `block in <class:ChefSolo>'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.1.5/plugins/provisioners/chef/provisioner/chef_solo.rb:53:in `provision'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a bug in Vagrant or Vagrant Windows. I would recommended opening an issue on GitHub.